# Why do I receive "ERROR TypeError: _this.getX is not a function" when the method is called in my update function?

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am working on an angular app where I want to reload my data table after updating one of the row items. When I try to reload the data table the error listed inside the title above is thrown.

### My data table component

```
    export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
    public id: number;
    public table: TableData[];
    public rowData: TableData;

  constructor(private compService: CompService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getX(this.id);
  }

  getX(id: number){
    this.compService
      .getTable(id)
      .subscribe(
        data => this.table = data,
        error =>  this.errorMessage = error
      );
  }

  saveChanges(){
    this.compService
      .updateRow(this.rowData)
      .subscribe(
        data => true,
        error => {
          this.errorMessage = error;
          console.log(this.errorMessage);
        },
        () => {
          console.log("Changes saved");
          this.getX(this.id);
      })
  }
```

### The service I use to make the requests

```
export class CompService {
  private Url = '...';

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  getTable(id: number){
    const url = `...`;
    return this.http
      .get(url)
      .map(response => response.json())
      .catch(this.handleError)
  }

  updateRow(rowData: RowData){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

    const url = `...`;
    return this.http
      .put(url, JSON.stringify(rowData), options)
      .map( response => response.json())
      .do(data => console.log('Update-Response: ' + JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data || null))))
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: Response | any) {
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

When my get method inside my ListComponent is called, the table get's loaded without any problems. When the update method calls the get method to reload the table the error listed inside the title is shown inside my browser console.
The update method is working. After refreshing the page the data is updated.

Can someone explain the error background and help me to fix it?

Thanks in advance, your help is appreciated.

Comment: Okay I figured it out. My bad, I did not mention using the saveChanges() method in another component where I did not include the get method with the Input() option.

Answer (score 0):

You have a scoping issue: you are creating a new object here:

```
() => {
```

In that object, there is no function called getX.

Comment: Not true, arrow function does not create new context. And this syntax is just for multiline function body, it does not create object.

Comment: How exactly do I create a new object with my complete block? I thought the complete block defines what I want to do after the request received a response sucessfuly.